# Oracle Apex past Value using Dynamic Link Item

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex, apex-code

So I have a link on my SQL query. It can navigate to the next page. But the thing is, I cannot carry the host_id(PK) to the next page: Anyone suggestion?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenate it.

```
select 
'...:P39_COPY_HOST_ID:' || host_id ||'"...'
from ...                -------------
                        this
```

---

Or, even better, `use apex_page.get_url` function:

```
select ...
  '<a href="' ||
    apex_page.get_url(p_page   => 39,
                      p_items  => 'P39_COPY_HOST_ID',
                      p_values => host_id)
              || '"</a>' as link
from ...
```

Comment: I did try this approach, but experiencing error: "No checksum was provided to show processing for a page that requires a checksum when one or more request, clear cache, or argument values are passed as parameters."

Comment: How about GET_URL function? See edited answer.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the idea.. Got resolved by modifying the column to below: 

 CASE
        WHEN nvl(column, 0) = 0 THEN '<a href="'
                                              || apex_util.prepare_url('f?p=&APP_ID.:39:&APP_SESSION.:::39:P39_HOST_ID:' || host_id
                                              )
                                              || '"><span class="fa fa-warning" aria-hidden="true" style="color:orange"></span></a>'
        ELSE '<span style="color: black;">'
             || column
             || '</span>'
    END column_sample,